# ECHO out most popular hashtags

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I've looked at a couple of examples on overflow of how to echo out the most popular words from a given query however what I'm curious to know is how would I echo out the most popular hash-tags; Lets say for example I have selected all the subjects from my users. many of these subjects include hash-tags for example. `Welcome to my chatroom #fun #awesome talk to me!` and this information for all my users would be gathered in the following statement.

**My Current Select Statement**

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT subject FROM usr_users WHERE gender = 'M'")or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 
echo $row['subjects'];
}?>
```

I'm just curious on how I would echo just the hashtags used which have the most frequent usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT subject, count(usr_users.subject)as subjectCount FROM usr_users WHERE gender = 'M'
GROUP BY usr_users.subject
ORDER BY subjectCount DESC
")or die(mysql_error());
$maxLines = 10;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
  echo $row['subject'].' ('.$row['subject'].' x)';
  $maxLines--;
  if( 0 == $maxLines )
   break;
}
?>
```

Should give you the 10 most common subjects.

Comment: Hey, thankyou for responding however this isn't what I'm after; I need it to just echo out the top 10 most popular hashtags. the problem I have is that the hashtags are mixed with regular words. so like I said in my example the subject would look like this `Welcome to my room #awesome #talk` lets say two people are using the #awesome hashtag and its the only hashtag being used it would then only echo out #awesome thankyou for the help though

Comment: Imagine the subject like a tweet where to get the trending hashtags it would search though all the subjects in this case and grab the most popular hashtags